# Error on running repository

Tags: command-line

On running this command

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:clipgrab-team/ppa
```

I obtain thee following error:

```
Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:~clipgrab-team/ubuntu/ppa'.
ERROR: '~clipgrab-team' user or team does not exist.
```

please post a solution

Comment: The problem is likely network connectivity. Are you using a proxy server with APT?

Answer (score 0):

As Chai T. Rex mention in his comment, I think this is a network connectivity issue (maybe you're behind a proxy, if that's the case the solution is below), because I executed right now this command:

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:clipgrab-team/ppa`

And it's working perfectly, see the output below.

```
galoget@hackem:~$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:clipgrab-team/ppa
 This PPA contains the latest stable version of ClipGrab for LTS releases. For other versions see <http://www.getdeb.net/app/ClipGrab>

Requires ffmpeg. As Ubuntu 14.04 dropped ffmpeg, a symlink from /usr/bin/avconv to /usr/bin/ffmpeg will be created as a workaround. 

Installation instructions for the terminal:

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:clipgrab-team/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install clipgrab

Alternatively you can add ppa:clipgrab-team/ppa to your system's Software Sources in the Ubuntu Software-Center. If you want to upgrade your system, please remove clipgrab and clipgrab-team/ppa first.
 More info: https://launchpad.net/~clipgrab-team/+archive/ubuntu/ppa
Press [ENTER] to continue or Ctrl-c to cancel adding it.

gpg: keybox '/tmp/tmplgjtx7zm/pubring.gpg' created
gpg: /tmp/tmplgjtx7zm/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
gpg: key D8AD4DE78EEBB0CA: public key "Launchpad ClipGrab PPA" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1
OK
```

In case you're behind a proxy server, please use the following commands:

1. Export `HTTP` and `HTTPS` proxy variables:

   `export http_proxy=http://<proxy>:<port>`

   `export https_proxy=http://<proxy>:<port>`
2. Tell `sudo` to preserve the environment with the `-E` flag.

   `sudo -E add-apt-repository ppa:linaro-maintainers/toolchain`

In case you need to authenticate with username and password please follow this structure for environment variables:

`export https_proxy=https://<username>:<password>@<proxy>:<port>`

Hope it helps.

Comment: Please don't use images for terminal output. Instead, paste the text into your answer, select the text, and press the `{}` button.